# confused about Solr Django and Haystack installation

Tags: python, django, solr

I'm following the tutorial in the Haystack  for using solr in django. I download haystack ad it to my installed apps, and I like to check my development to make sure my apps still working. So when I go to my my localhost it says

```
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.
```

and in my terminal it says

```
raise MissingDependency("The 'solr' backend requires the installation of 'pysolr'. Please refer to the documentation.")
```

and when I go to the pysolr documentation it seems as if it's to be used without haystack. There is no mention pysolr in haystack docs and no mention of haystack in pysolr docs. Not only that, but pysolr gives an example that says

```
# If on Python 2.X
```

Im using python 3. I understand theres a learning curve but is there anything that has all the resources in one post? Or must I just trial and error it out? and also can it be Kind of up to date? 2.x to 3.5 is a big gap. There are surprisingly no google videos or vimeo videos on this. any and all help is welcome. I know anything worth having or knowing isn't easy to come by but sheesh? the few sites Ive seen also have the url like this in urls.py

```
(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
```

but if I do it like that I get an error

```
 regex_pattern = pattern.regex.pattern
```

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'regex'

this may seem like nothing to someone experienced, but to the untrained this can lead to a lot of confusion to the proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Haystack [uses different adapters to talk to different backend services](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing_search_engines.html), such as ElasticSearch or Solr.

The Solr adapter uses pysolr:

> You’ll also need a Solr binding, pysolr. The official pysolr package, distributed via PyPI, is the best version to use (2.1.0+). Place pysolr.py somewhere on your PYTHONPATH.

You shouldn't have to do anything with pysolr yourself, as that is only used inside the haystack Solr adapter. Be sure to follow the tutorial for setting up the schema and getting the indexing running.

Comment: thanks for the response but I'm through with that all those tutorials are outdated and certain versions don't mesh with certain versions. I was using the latest django, python, solr and haystack. found out you cant use the latest haystack with the latest solr. So I used solr 4.10.4, that didn't work so I used 4.10.2 that didn't work. there arent ANY videos that are recent and show how to use these technologies together. None of these things are well documented. As much as technolgy changes you would think these docs would be updated to at LEAST 6 mos behind. I'll get it though

Comment: I have followed these tutorials verbatim. Thought the problem was my config only to find out latest versions don't play nice with other latest version. Tutorials telling me to start solr server not working. It's a bit dainting

Answer (score 0):

just pip install pysolr and move about your day.

Personally, I used(in my virtual env):

```
python3 -m pip install pysolr
```